# How do I send data to this checkbox using python with selenium web-driver

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate this webpage and send some data to a checkbox with a dynamic @id.

I have used sample codes I found online but the test keeps failing due to not finding the element.

XPath for the webpage text box: //*[@id="undefined-Filter-undefined-24212"]

[image]
element:

In the snipped provided, the 24212 int is dymanic.

Comment: This worked for me: 
`code` 
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id, 'undefined-Filter-undefined')]") `code`

Since only the end of the ID is dynamic and there is no other ID on the page that matches this once-- I was able to get away using contain....

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like and instead of name use x_path:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

For reference : https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: There is no name in the html though. Sorry it didn't post the first time... I had to add a screenshot of the html